# IE9 url caching issue

Tags: caching, https, refresh, internet-explorer-9

I have a strange caching issue going on with IE9.  The other day I set up a new website on my IIS server that was NOT running HTTPS, unfortunately I accidentally setup a redirect to HTTPS if you entered in HTTP.  So because I didn't have it setup, the webpage didn't load becasue no HTTPS was running.  I subsequently fixed the issue in IIS, and when I hit the web page with browsers other than IE9 it seems to work fine.  For some reason in IE9 it just wont load the webpage (I think it is still trying to hit it on HTTPS).

I have tried clearing all temp files/cookies etc.., rebooted and still no luck. The only way I have been able to get IE9 to hit the web page was by going into 'F12 Developer Tools' and turn on "Always refresh from server" under the 'Cache' menu option.  As soon as I turn that on it starts working.  I turn it off and I cannot hit the website again.

Is there some other cache for IE9 that I don't know about that doesn't get cleared through normally processes?

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem similar with yours. I fixed it by adding a random number in URL. Just like this: .....Index.asp?random=3283237431, hope this can help you.